# Make a transparent circle button with an opaque border and text / font awesome icon

Tags: html, css

Basically I want a sexy, responsive circle button that is transparent so you can see the background through it, but with an opaque outline so you can see the button and opaque text (or maybe I will add a font-awesome icon at a later stage).

Here is my JS fiddle so you can see what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/njd2g94u/

```
.round-button {
    width:25%;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:10px solid #98a1a4;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:10px solid #98a1a4;
    overflow:hidden;

    background: #fff; 
    background-opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background:#30588e;
}
.round-button a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;

    text-align:center;
    color:#e2eaf3;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ehm... remove the `background: #fff`?

Comment: It would help if you could indicate to what extent this CSS does not provide what you want and what you have tried so that you don't get answers which you have already tried or ruled out

Comment: umm... it was answered, and what more CSS would I need to include? Just go to the JSFiddle to see what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `background-opacity`. May be you are looking for this:

```css
.round-button-circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #98a1a4;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent; /* Change it to transparent */
  /* remove background-opacity */
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xppow236/**

Answer (score 1):

you can and should use rgba for colors with transparency. The last parameter is the transparency level, any number from 0 to 1. The color below is roughly equivalent to "#98a1a4."

```
border: 10px solid rgba(151, 162, 164, 0.25);
```